# Fails when running WCF service with certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have a windows service hosting a WCF service with the following configuration.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Carglass.Movil.Service.CarglassService" behaviorConfiguration="CarglassServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9002/CarglassServiceAGI" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="Carglass.Movil.Service.ICarglassService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CarglassServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=MWMWCF"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The certificate is installed on the machine and the **Network Service** user is running the windows service as **local administrator**. Permissions has been granted by running the following **command**

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9002/CarglassServiceAGI user="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

... and by managing **private keys within mmc.exe giving "Full control"** to that user.

But I got the following exception every time I try to run my service:

> System.ArgumentException: It is likely that certificate 'CN=MWMWCF' may not have a private key that is capable of key exchange or the process may not have access rights for the private key. Please see inner exception for detail.\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.EnsureCertificateCanDoKeyExchange(X509Certificate2 certificate)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateServerX509TokenProvider()\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateLocalSecurityTokenProvider(RecipientServiceModelSecurityTokenRequirement recipientRequirement)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateSecurityTokenProvider(SecurityTokenRequirement requirement)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateTlsnegoServerX509TokenProvider(RecipientServiceModelSecurityTokenRequirement recipientRequirement)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateTlsnegoSecurityTokenAuthenticator(RecipientServiceModelSecurityTokenRequirement recipientRequirement, Boolean requireClientCertificate, SecurityTokenResolver& sctResolver)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateSecurityTokenAuthenticator(SecurityTokenRequirement tokenRequirement, SecurityTokenResolver& outOfBandTokenResolver)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenAuthenticator.SessionRenewSecurityTokenManager.CreateSecurityTokenAuthenticator(SecurityTokenRequirement tokenRequirement, SecurityTokenResolver& outOfBandTokenResolver)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocolFactory.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocolFactory.Open(Boolean actAsInitiator, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityListenerSettingsLifetimeManager.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenAuthenticator.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenAuthenticator.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.OpenCommunicationObject(ICommunicationObject obj, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.OpenTokenAuthenticatorIfRequired(SecurityTokenAuthenticator tokenAuthenticator, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionServerSettings.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionServerSettings.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityListenerSettingsLifetimeManager.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()\r\n   at MWM.Service.WindowsService.AGI.ServiceController.OnStart(String[] args) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\MWM-Refactor\MWM.Service\MWM.Service.WindowsService.AGI\ServiceController.cs:line 45

Works fine if I remove this from the configuration:

```
<message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
```

Comment: That netsh command does not grant access to the primary key.

Comment: I made a mistake in the netsh command in the url. Edited. Is that what you pointed?

Comment: No. That netsh command grants the service the rights to host a service on that URL. It doesn't do anything with certificates. See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184586/wcf-error-it-is-likely-that-certificate-my-cert-may-not-have-a-private-key).

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster those steps are done already and still not working fine. Network Service is local admin and has full control of the Certificate keys.

Answer (score 0):

This post explains how to build your certificates properly and how to install them providing the enough rights to have all working:
http://returnsmart.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-create-your-own-signed.html