# How to make sure Client Certificate is passed to Server

Tags: wcf, fiddler, client-certificates

I have an application that needs to communicate with a third-party SOAP/WCF API using a client certificate. I have tried everything on the web how to call SOAP/WCF API using a client certificate. But every time I am getting a client certificate authentication failed. Is there is a way to see whether I am passing the client certificate or not? Fiddler is not showing whether the client cert is sent with the request or not.

Comment: WireShark to the rescue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/nettracer/how-it-works-on-the-wire-iis-http-client-certificate-authentication

Comment: If we use custom certificate verification, we can check whether the client has transmitted a self-signed certificate. For more information about custom certificate verification, you can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64616269/how-to-perform-ssl-user-authentication/64628139#64628139

Comment: Thanks, @DingPeng how can we check whether the certificate transmitted from the client to server or not

Comment: We can check the certificate by implementing the X509CertificateValidator interface. X509CertificateValidator contains the Validate method. In the Validate method, we can determine whether the certificate is empty.